# How to find number of coins in the coin change problem

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

We have an infinite supply of coins, each having some value. Can you figure out the minimum number of coins required so that the coins will sum-up to a certain required value? We'll use dynamic programming to solve this question.

But if I want to know which coin is used and how many times, How will I do it?

I tried this but it is not providing me the right Input.

```
int findForYes(vector<int> coins,int V,int coinNumber[M][N])
{
    if (V == 0) return 0; 
    int res = INT_MAX; 

    for (int i=0; i<coins.size(); i++)  
      if (coins[i] <= V) 
       { 
         int sub_res = findForYes(coins, V-coins[i]); 
         if (sub_res != INT_MAX && sub_res + 1 < res) 
         {
           res = sub_res + 1;   
           coinNumber[V][coins[i]]++;
         }
        }

   return res; 
}
```

coinNumber[M][N] represents the sum of M having all N coins, V represents the sum to be obtained.

Suppose coins are [10, 5, 15] and we have to make the change of 25 then one of the combinations is 1 times 10, 0 times 5 and 1 times 15 hence the output should be [1, 0, 5]

Comment: `not prividing me right input`. Could you detail a little bit and provide an example of input and incorrect result?

Comment: I edit and provide example!! there may be many ways!! but we want one with minimum number of coins

Answer (score 0):

So from what I understand, you want to solve the CoinChange problem but not only to return the minimal number of coins required to combine the amount, but also the coins themselves. 
I wrote something in Java, hope it helps.

public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
        if (coins == null || amount < 0) return -1;
        int[] dp = new int[amount + 1]; // dp[i] = the minimal number of which we need to create i sum.
        Arrays.fill(dp, amount + 1); // initialize the array with amount+1;
        dp[0] = 0;

```
    List<List<Integer>> lst = new ArrayList<>(); // lst(i) will contain the minimal combination of coins that sums to i.
    lst.add(new ArrayList<>()); // add the combination for 0

    for (int i = 1; i <= amount; i++) {
        List<Integer> currentCoinCombination = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int coin : coins) {
            if (i - coin < 0) continue;
            if (dp[i-coin] < dp[i]){
                dp[i] = dp[i - coin] + 1;
                currentCoinCombination = new ArrayList<>(lst.get(i-coin));
                currentCoinCombination.add(coin);
            }
        }
        lst.add(currentCoinCombination);
    }

    return dp[amount] == amount + 1 ? -1 : dp[amount];
}
```

keep in mind that the combination of coins you are looking for will be in lst.get(amount);